# How to use '@app/....' references in Angular 7 instead of literal paths?

Tags: angular, import, path, reference, export

Trying to set up our product to not require much/any reference changes if a control gets moved.

When I use a pre-built app from aspnetboilerplate.com all of their service/component/pipe/directive references are imported based on an "@app/etc" path instead of a literal path from the file exported into and I would like to be able to use that but it doesn't seem to work natively.

the boilerplate structure is the same as an app generated with ng new but they can use

```js
import { SomeService } from '@app/services/some-service.service';
```

instead of

```js
import { SomeService } from '../../../services/some-service.service';
```

but that doesn't work within our app and I can't figure out how they set it up

Cannot find module '@app/services/some-service.service' is all i get :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is related to Typescript compiler, so you need to update your tsconfig.json file as following:

Add to "paths" property this value

```
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "paths": {
      // ...
      "@app/*": ["app/*"] 
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the tsconfig.json file where the magic happens. It allows to define mappings between a specifier and a file path.

You can find the official documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Netanel Basal also wrote an article about it: 
https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6